# react-native Animated jittery motion

Tags: ios, performance, animation, react-native

I'm trying to figure out why my animation is so jittery. I'm using the Animated library and transforming the y position of a view. I'm about to add about 30-40 more views of this kind to the screen but worried about overall jittery performance. The motion jumps strangely even on my iphone 6+.

Here's an rn playground file to see what I mean:

https://rnplay.org/apps/1TT9ew

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need Easing.

```
import {
  Animated,
  Easing
} from 'react-native';

...

Animated.timing(this.state.scale, {
  toValue: 1.3,
  duration: 2000,
  easing: Easing.linear
})
```